# An array with the terms that are the differences of consecutive terms (adjacent) in another array

Tags: java, arrays, double

I currently have:

```
    public double[] differences()
    {
     diffs = new doublae[sequence.length-1];
     for (int = 0; i<sequence.length; ++i){
     double diff = sequence[i+1] - sequence[i];
     diffs[i] = diff;
    }
    return diffs;
    }
```

However this does not work when i run a test program to check it.

Comment: what is a `doublae` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat typo I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You range should be different - `i` shouldn't pass `sequence.length - 2` in order for `i+1` to be a valid index.

```
double[] diffs = new double[sequence.length-1];
for (int = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) { // changed the condition
 double diff = sequence[i+1] - sequence[i];
 diffs[i] = diff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help that worked perfectly. Would it also work if i changed it to `double diff = sequence[i] - sequence[i-1];`

Comment: @ZainSoemya Then you'd have to change the loop to `for (int = 1; i < sequence.length; i++)`